# Regarding pre-installed firefox

Tags: firefox

I have recently dual booted my windows with ubuntu 20.04. And with that I have got firefox pre-installed but when I go to the app store, I see another firefox. I don't understand the difference between the two. Is one better than the other or are they the same?

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

Comment: Look at the `Source` - if it says `snapcraft.io` then it's offering a `Snap` packaged install rather than an `apt` package. Some differences and advantages/disadvantages to both package methods. Often nowadays the Ubuntu store lists both a snap version and an apt version of software but you have to drill down to see which is which (poor design IMO). The store should be clearer about which is which and also offer good links to resources explaining the differences of snaps and apts.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same or 1 is a predecessor of the other.

So note the [SNAPCRAFT](https://snapcraft.io/) reference with the 2nd as this denotes that the installation is method using snap.

You can install different firefoxes from

- regular Ubuntu apt repository
- snapstore
- directly from Mozilla

Depending on versions and packaging those can be 3 different installs.

Comment: So, which is better ? I sometimes find that youtube or web whatsapp in firefox I am using now takes some time to fully load.

Comment: No idea. "better" is too vague ;-) I always go with "If it works it works". YT and WA being slow does not have to be cuz of FF. I would also compare it with chrome if I was you

Comment: @RakeshGoud I would say the list is in order of usefulness. Normally I prefer the "regular Ubuntu apt repository" first, the one that is done with `sudo apt install ...`. If for some reason that's not satisfactory, then I might look at the snapstore variant. If neither are available, but the author of a software has published `deb` packages on their website (e.g. the manufacturer of my printer publishes some printer-specific drivers on their website), then those could be considered.

Comment: Snaps and .debs usually install a bit differently.  Snaps are usually restricted on what they can do by permissions, which you can adjust.  If not paying attention, you might wonder why you can't print from a browser anymore.  Would try both and see which one works better for you.